# Count occurrence of id across multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

Ok, what am I doing wrong here. This should be simple...

I have a table that isn't normalized. I want to get a count of the IDs that appear in three columns of the table.

```
1    100 200 300
2    200 700 800
3    200 300 400
4    100 200 300
```

result:

```
2    100
4    200
3    300
1    400
1    700
1    800
```

Here is my attempt. The the union works. It is my attempt to sum and group them that fails:

```
select sum(cnt), ICDCodeID from
(
    select count(*) cnt, ICDCodeID1 ICDCodeID from encounter
    where (ICDCodeID1 is not null) group by ICDCodeID1
    UNION ALL
    select count(*) cnt, ICDCodeID2 ICDCodeID from encounter
    where (ICDCodeID2 is not null) group by ICDCodeID2
    UNION ALL
    select count(*) cnt, ICDCodeID3 ICDCodeID from encounter
    where (ICDCodeID3 is not null) group by ICDCodeID3
) group by cnt, ICDCodeID
```

Or better way?

Here is the error I am getting: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'."

Comment: That's the cookbook solution for this kind of problem. You're doing just fine.

Comment: Mureinik, but where is my error?

Comment: What error? Your post stated this works...

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.

Comment: Why am I getting down votes. I made a simple error and asked for help. I gave my attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
SELECT D.ICDCode, 
       COUNT(*) as Cnt
  FROM(SELECT ICDCodeID1 AS ICDCode
         FROM encounter
        UNION
          ALL 
       SELECT ICDCodeID2 AS ICDCode
         FROM encounter
        UNION
          ALL 
       SELECT ICDCodeID3 AS ICDCode
         FROM encounter
      )D
 GROUP
    BY D.ICDCode;
```

Comment: same error that I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'."

Comment: @ginalster now you can try error may be due to missing alias

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-- build sample data
create table temp(
    id int,
    col1 int,
    col2 int,
    col3 int
)
insert into temp
select 1, 100, 200, 300 union all 
select 2, 200, 700, 800 union all 
select 3, 200, 300, 400 union all 
select 4, 100, 200, 300

-- start
;with cte(id, col_value) as(
    select id, col1 from temp union all
    select id, col2 from temp union all
    select id, col3 from temp
)
select
    col_value,
    count(*)
from cte
group by col_value
-- end

-- clean sample data
drop table temp
```

Comment: I would prefer a single sql statement but if that can't be done I will try this. Thx